# Residence Permit translation

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, spouses

Do i have to translate my Hungarian residence permit to apply to UK visitor Visa?
Do i need to provide them with my family book translated or my marriage certificate translated ?

Comment: UK is not in Schengen even if it is in Europe, so you may apply for a VISA even if it is a visit for less than 90 days (in case you do not know, you can travel in any Schengen country only with a Schengen PR and your passport with no need of a visa if your stay is less than 90 days). I don't think you have to, because a consulate, as a governmental entity, certainly knows the format of nearly all documents issued by various countries, and the meaning of them. By the way take the safe road and translate it

Answer (score 2):

EU residence permits are in a common format, you should not need to get it translated. As for any other documents you are providing, the UKVI ‘Guide to Supporting Documents’ states:

“ All documents must be originals and not photocopies. Submission of these documents does not guarantee that your application will be successful and you should bear this in mind when making any bookings.

If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be accompanied by a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office. Each translated document must contain:

- confirmation from the translator that it is an accurate translation of the original document
- the date of the translation
- the translator’s full name and signature
- the translator’s contact details”

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Comment: EU residence permits are different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to present it alongside your passport but they shouldn't need a translation. (They may need other documents you provide translated though.)